# Почему не работает margin: 0 auto в ie7

Tags: css

UPD Вопрос решен.

http://vtest.uphero.com/Landing_page/ 
первая же форма на странице в ие7 имеет баг.
В ней Input уезжает влево, хотя явно задан стиль - 
display: block; 
margin: 0 auto;
2 часа пыталась понять причину такого поведения - не получилось :(....
В чем ошибка? Как сделать, чтобы input был по центру?

Answer (score 1):

Все потому, что для IE7 такая конструкция `header[role="banner"] .row2 .get-access p + input[type=text]` все равно, что барану математику учить. Он не умеет с такими селекторами работать, 
[role=text] 
p + input

Вы ему показали такое а он в шоке и потому ничего не делает

Comment: Но ведь другие параметры в этих селекторах он же понимает. Не работает маргин уже отсюда: 
header[role="banner"] .row2 .get-access input[type=text],
header[role="banner"] .row2 .get-access input[type=email] {
}
Вертикальные отступы он же все разметил как положено.

Comment: Нашла причину, но не понимаю WTF???
У самой формы стоит margin-right. И он почему-то сдвигает текстовые поля влево. Если убрать этот параметр - блоки выравниваются по центру.